# calculation to arrange spheres in a ring

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to arrange 10 spheres in a ring. This is the calculation I have put together so far, but it is not working

```
            var bubbleGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(300, 20, 20);
            var bubbleMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } );
            var numBubbles = 10;
            var bubbleMesh;
            var bubbles = [];
            var startX = 0;
            var startY = 500;
            var spacing = 80 * Math.sin( angle );
            for (var i=0; i<numBubbles; i++) {
                bubbleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(bubbleGeo, bubbleMat);
                console.log("bubble" + i);
                var angle = 360/numBubbles*i*Math.PI/180;
                bubbleMesh.position.set((startX + Math.cos(angle)*bubbleR) + spacing, 
                                        (startY + Math.sin(angle)*bubbleR) + spacing, 
                                        100
                                        );
                scene.add(bubbleMesh);
                bubbles.push(bubbleMesh);
            }
```

I don't really know much about math.  If any folks are there who do see where I have went wrong, any help would be greatly appreicated.  Thanks!

Comment: So what did go wrong?  What result did you get and how did it vary from the result you epxected?

Comment: I can't understand your angle variable. I think you need parentheses there. Also, a jsfiddle link can be helpful...

Comment: Woot hey guys thanks for your posts.

What was going wrong was it wasn't showing at all.  Even though I have been able to fix this issue you're right, I should post a fiddle of this project because it still has a ways to go.  but right now, here is the corrected equation:

Answer (score 0):

```
            var bubbleR = 400;
            var bubbleGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(bubbleR, 10, 10);
            var bubbleMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } );
            var numBubbles = 5;
            var bubbleMesh;
            bubbles = [];
            var startX = 1000;
            var startZ = 1000;
            for (var i=0; i<numBubbles; i++) {
                bubbleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(bubbleGeo, bubbleMat);
                var angle = 360/numBubbles*i*Math.PI/180;
                bubbleMesh.position.set((startX + Math.sin(angle)*bubbleR) * 2, 
                                         1000, 
                                         startZ + (Math.cos(angle)*bubbleR) * 2
                );
                scene.add(bubbleMesh);
                bubbles.push(bubbleMesh);       
            }
```

For some reason, if I add the array to the scene after the loop, it doesn't work.  Also I wish they were in a new THREE.group, so I could position the whole group, but that doesn't seem to work at the moment either